# Mail Chimp RSS Feed

Tags: merge, rss, mailchimp

I have a campaign set up using Mail Chimp and I have hit a problem. Right now the feed uses FEED Merge tags but they have to be changed in order to use RSS Merge tags. e.g. "*|RSSFEED:URL|*" and so on but the problem is that I want to pull through 5 items or less at a time from a specific feed including images but it only pulls through one.

I have read Mail Chimps documentation and can't seem to get it working. Any help would be fantastic.

Please find my code below.

Thanks
Harry

*|FEEDBLOCK:http://engage.colt.net/en/feed|* *|RSSITEMS:[$count=5]|*
*|RSSITEM:IMAGE|*
*|RSSITEM:TITLE|*
*|RSSITEM:CONTENT|

*|END:RSSITEMS|* *|END:FEEDBLOCK|*

Answer (score 0):

Change RSSITEMS to FEEDITEMS throughout and you should be ok:

|FEEDBLOCK:http://engage.colt.net/en/feed| |**FEEDITEMS:**[$count=5]| |**FEEDITEM**:IMAGE|
|**FEEDITEM**:TITLE| *|**FEEDITEM**:CONTENT|

|END:**FEEDITEMS**| |END:FEEDBLOCK|